# How could I improve this question in order to get a response?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

Several days ago, I posted the following question which was subsequently labeled a "tumbleweed". There have been no votes, no comments, nothing. It's not at all clear to me what would help make this question sufficiently interesting to the community to make it worthy of a response.

It seems to me that it must be relevant to more people than just myself since this issue arose on a fresh install of RedHat on a popular enterprise desktop PC (Dell OptiPlex). What is the missing ingredient that would make this question more enticing? I would place a bounty on it, but I don't have enough points on this site yet to do that.

[Why are AMD's graphics drivers not working?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368345/why-are-amds-graphics-drivers-not-working)

Comment: I read through the question and don't really see anything wrong with it. It may just be that the number of folks here with relevant knowledge is small.

Comment: As derobert said, the question seems fine. Better than most, really. I put a bounty on it which might help get some more attention.

Comment: I answered the question two days ago, due the the bounty and lack of answers. Is it complete, or is there something I can improve?